# Apache VirtualHosts - Exclude multiple files and a folder from domain redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, vhosts

Using this code:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^((?!.*?excluded_file\.php).*)$ http://newdomain.com$1
```

...I'm currently redirecting all requests to my Apache server from olddomain.com to newdomain.com, except for one file called excluded_file.php. But I actually need to exclude ALL files requested that start with "excluded_" (excluded_1.php, excluded_2.php, excluded_3.php) as well as any request to files in the folder "olddomainfiles". So the end result is:

**Will redirect to newdomain.com/whatevertherequestwasfor:**

```
http://olddomain.com/somerandomfile.php
http://olddomain.com/otherfolders/whateverfile.php
http://olddomain.com/nice_URL_without_file_extension_or_slash
```

**Will NOT redirect:**

```
http://olddomain.com/olddomainfiles/anyfile.php
http://olddomain.com/exclude_1.php
http://olddomain.com/exclude_2.php
http://olddomain.com/exclude_3.php
```

Why I need this: I just submitted my app to Apple and decided at the last minute that I needed to change the domain name, which breaks one feature of the app because it's relying explicitly on seeing the old domain name -- it doesn't see it anymore because of the changes made to my virtual hosts file. I posted about this problem a couple days ago but I was wrong about what I needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^((?!.*?(excluded.*\.php|olddomainfiles)).*)$ http://newdomain.com$1
```

Just needed to change the negative look ahead (which was looking for `excluded_file\.php` before) to be an option of either `excluded.*\.php` or `olddomainfiles`.

Comment: Perfect! Added an underscore to the `excluded.*\.php` and it's working great! Thanks!